# MSBuild, TeamCity, SVN: Best practice for reliable targetting of test/dev/live builds/configs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, msbuild, teamcity

I wonder if I could get some feedback from people on how to best approach building of Visual Studio solutions.

My core requirements would be to ensure that any code/tests run against the correct resources, in particular, database schema and sample data.

I've tried various ways to do this with mixed degrees of success. Currently, I …

- Create a class library *.Installation.dll, which creates, configures
  and populates the database, etc.
- Have a class library *.Build.dll
  which has an MSBuild task that takes parameters from the csproj file
  and passes to the Installation.dll.

These sit within their own solution. Say MyApp.Build.sln. I maintain this separately from my main solution, to prevent file locking issues.

In my main solution, say MyApp.sln …

Then, my test projects invoke the MSBuild task to create test environments for integration testing including database and sample test data.
And my Web/Windows front end projects invoke the MSBuild to create runnable environments for test users/my manual testing

So, I am using MSBuild to create customisable builds/environments for testing/running. Additionally, I can wrap the Installation.dll into a configuration/setup tool to automate the installation for the user when the time comes to install.

Is this too complex a scenario? I'm worried I've over engineered this and overlooked something. It works well, but is bound by a lot of meta programming (eg. the database build code, configuration, build task, etc.) that is not directly involved with tangible, chargeable work.

I have SubVersion and TeamCity. I'd like to enable a CI build ultimately that is invokes on a daily/commit build trigger. Or can I use TeamCity in such a way to avoid rebuilding the database/etc. every build?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: @Program_X, now that it's been a year, how is this working for you? We use Teamcity and SVN. We have a dll for the database connection instantiation, that definitely works well. It doesn't populate data, we do that separately. I wonder if maybe the test db population should be separated from the connection part for production? I'm a newbie so not sure I can offer more advice, but curious to hear what others are doing.

Comment: @AnneTheAgile: It's not quite been a year, I suspect you may be confused by the American date format ;) (me too). It feels like a year, though. I think since our esteemed peers haven't chimed in I'm either way off the mark or I hit the nail on the head. This set-up is working really well. We haven't yet put it into TeamCity, but other than that, it works like a dream. The test data is only added in test scenarios, by a flag in the MSBuild script. I am intending on blogging this in the very near future. I just need to find time, and will update this when I do. Glad you're on similar lines!